# SELECT Query is slow when run remotely in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

When I connect MySQL from remote server and run below query then the results are very slow(Sometime even faced lost connection Issue). However when I run the same SQL query on the local machine then It's results are very fast.

```
    SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS
```

The customer tale contains two million records.

I have also enable skip-host-cache and skip-name-resolve in MySQL configuration.

Both machine is connected using the LAN IP and customer table is InnoDB table. I am using MySQL 5.6.

Can you please suggest me on this, why SQL query are very slow when run It from remote machine.

Thank you,
Sujeet

Comment: What is the ping time between the machines?

Comment: WHY do you want to fetch a million rows?  WHAT can you do with that much data all at once?  Can't you process the data in the database and return only a few rows?

Comment: Below is the ping time between the machine:

`Reply from 10.7.209.12: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
 Reply from 10.7.209.12: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
 Reply from 10.7.209.12: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
 Reply from 10.7.209.12: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
 Reply from 10.7.209.12: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128`

We have a requirements to extract at least 5 thousand records at a time and process that. When we are extracting 5 thousand records then It takes times to give the results and sometime we get timeout or Lost connection error message. 
Please help on this.

Comment: *"When we are extracting 5 thousand records"* Your query isn't doing that.  It's fetching all of them.

Comment: @Michal When you connect MySQL remotely and fetch 5000 records like 
`select * from table_name LIMIT 5000` then Its still takes times and sometimes we get Lost connection error message.

Comment: How do you tell that "SQL is very slow"? It must be told from the query execution time on the server side, otherwise, you'll get some latency from network (transport, name resolution, firewall, or whatever in between)

Answer (score 0):

`LIMIT` will work for the first 5000, but will get slower and slower as you move on (with `OFFSET`) to subsequent chunks.  So that's not a good way to process a large table in chunks.

Does the table have a `PRIMARY KEY`?  (If not, why not?)  Use that for very efficient chunking.  It will avoid the timeouts you are getting.

[*A discussion of chunking*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks).  (That is aimed at `DELETE`, but it can easily be adapted to `SELECT`.)  The trick is to "remember where you left off".

Comment: We are using `PRIMARY KEY` and It is still very slow. I have also used MySQLTuner to check the configuration and my configuration is also good as per Mysqltuner script.

Comment: _Having_ a `PRIMARY KEY` is not the same as _using it_ for chunking.  Please show the statement for the _second_ 5000 rows.